# Using image instead text in PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`, and I would like to have a picture in place of the title text ("**View1**", "**View2**" etc.). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

U can use this library.

It is easy to use  [JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)